# Error 500 Internal server updating table with AJAX POST

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm new with AJAX so probably I'm missing something. I'm finding a problem (Error 500 Internal server) while updating a mysql table through an external php source.

Basically I'm trying to do the following:

> click on button > call ajax function > call php > update mysql table.

I'm working with wordpress and MAMP.

Here is my code.

**1. Button**

```
<button onclick="unreadMessage()" class="messages btn btn-menu dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" type="button">
```

**2. jQuery / AJAX function**

```
function unreadMessage(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/lib/unread.php",
            data: { 'read': '1' },
            success:function() {
                alert("ok");
            }
        });
    }
```

**3. My external file code unread.php**

```
    global $current_user, $wpdb, $wp_query;
    get_currentuserinfo();
    $uid = $current_user->ID;
    $read = $_POST['read']; 
    $sql = "update ".$wpdb->prefix."project_pm set rd='$read' where id='{$row->id}' AND user='$uid' and notify='1'";
       if(mysqli_query($sql)){
       }
       else {
        return "failed!";
    }
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: `if(mysqli_query($sql)){` you're not connecting here. and check your logs. `return "failed!";` doesn't help you. Get the real error.

Comment: *...I smell an answer (in the works)*

Comment: Where is link identifier? In query?

Comment: mysqli query syntax:  mysqli_query(connection,query,resultmode);

Comment: Take a look to [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Comment: For what it's worth the PHP code contains a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: Add it as a function in functions.php and `add_action` to wp_ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well for next users passing by. To actually update a wordpress database through an ajax call triggered by buttons here is the correct way.

1. Insert action in functions.php
2. Call the action into jQuery / Ajax function
3. Link to the button.

you can find something helpful (at least for me) here [wordpress ajax not updating database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27286693/wordpress-ajax-not-updating-database).

Cheers.